# Contacts list and chat box disappeared from the left hand side of Google Mail

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

My contact list and chatbox has suddenly disappeared from the left hand side of Googlemail. It has disappeared on both my desktop and laptop computers.  I have changed my password but I have done nothing else.

How do I get it back?

Answer (score 6):

You can get back the Chat box by visiting the Gmail settings -> Under the "Chat" tab, expand *Additional chat settings* -> check the box "Chat On".

[image]

Comment: Disabling and enabling Chat seemed to help.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Bibhas’s answer, if you have the new Gmail layout/theme/UI, the chat can be shown/hidden by clicking on a bubble in the lower left corner (see the image below).

[image]